Numba JIT code runs twice as slow as original code
I am attempting to optimize a function I wrote to get the k Nearest Neighbors of a vector in python using Numba JIT. However, the Numba version of my code runs twice as slow as the original code. I assume I have made a mistake in my optimization as Numba JIT code should apparently faster by an order of magnitude.
My original code is below,
def __call__(self, x_test: list[list] | np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    x_test = np.asarray(x_test)
    y_test = np.empty(x_test.shape[0], dtype=self._y.dtype)
    for i in range(x_test.shape[0]):
        distances = np.linalg.norm(self._x - x_test[i], ord=self.ord, axis=1)
        label, count = np.unique(self._y[np.argsort(distances)[:min(self.k, self._y.shape[0])]], return_counts=True)
        y_test[i] = label[np.argmax(count)]
    return y_test

And the Numba optimized code below,
@overload(np.unique)
def np_unique(a):
    def np_unique_impl(a):
        b = np.sort(a.flatten())
        unique = list(b[:1])
        counts = [1 for _ in unique]
        for x in b[1:]:
            if x != unique[-1]:
                unique.append(x)
                counts.append(1)
            else:
                counts[-1] += 1
        return np.asarray(unique), np.asarray(counts)
    return np_unique_impl

@jit(nopython=True)
def jitter(x_train: np.ndarray, y_train: np.ndarray, k: int, ord: int, x_test: np.ndarray, y_test: np.ndarray):
    for i in range(x_test.shape[0]):
        distances = np.zeros(x_train.shape[0])
        for j in range(distances.shape[0]):
            distances[j] = np.linalg.norm(x_train[j]-x_test[i], ord=ord)
        label, count = np.unique(y_train[np.argsort(distances)[:min(k, y_train.shape[0])]])
        y_test[i] = label[np.argmax(count)]

On running both of the above on the same input of 100000 train points and 10000 test points, the Numba version is about twice as slow, running in 260 seconds, while the original runs in around 130 seconds. What have I done wrong in my Numba implementation?

Numba use its own implementation of Numpy. It may be faster or slower than the one of Numpy. For complex function like sorting ones, Numpy now use a better implementation (I do not expect Numba do use the same implementation or a faster one because they use an external optimized library). np.unique do a sort internally. In general, there is no reason to believe Numpy function calls in Numba functions are faster than Numpy ones (outside Numba functions) unless you operate on very small arrays. Numba is especially fast for code with plain loops ding basic array operation (ie. not Numpy calls).

If you want your Numba code to be as fast as Numpy one for np.sort (which should be the bottleneck), you should use the same implementation, that is the sorting library used by Numpy. However, it is not portable (only available on x86-64 CPU) and requires to load it with ctypes/CFFI and call it from Numba. This is not straightforward to do. An alternative solution is to do that in Cython or even a native CPython module (possibly in parallel to speed this code). I do not expect anyone to write a faster generic implementation of sort than the one of Numpy on x86-64 CPU so far.

@JérômeRichard I see, I was of the notion that Numba was almost always faster due to the JIT compilation. Thanks!

JIT compilation helps when Numpy overheads are the issue (or CPython ones). Here, I expect the sorting function to be the bottleneck and this function is already compiled in C and very optimized (more than anything you can do in Numba naively) as long as the target array is relatively big. The only benefit of using Numba would be to write a parallel code (which will certainly not scale well due to the sort), but the current one is sequential.

If you want to efficiently handle the K nearest neighbors for large data, I strongly recommend using KDTree.
